# go-redis connection to Amazon Elastic Redis Cluter

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, redis

Hi how can I connect my local golang code to Amazon Elastic Redis cluster with the help of go-redis sdk?

Answer (score 0):

With using [github.com/go-redis/redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) package , you can connect with Amazon Elastic Redis cluster

```
import "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"

client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     "the-aws-redis-cluster-host:port",
    Password: "optional-password",
})

state, err := client.Ping(context.Background()).Result()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(state)
```

Before connecting to the AWS redis cluster from local please make sure

- The cluster instance is configured to accept the connections from your IP
- The security group which is attached with the cluster allowing the incoming traffic on the port 6379.

Answer (score 0):

A note when using redis version less than 6.0.0 is that you need to leave your username empty. You also need to set up tls if your redis requires it. Here is an example code:

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    redisClient "github.com/redis/go-redis/v9"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)


// URL example: redis://username:password@host:port
opt, err := redisClient.ParseURL(${URL})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Remove username to avoid error: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'auth' command when using redis cloud
// Root cause: Redis before 6.0.0 does not support username in URL
// Reference: https://github.com/redis/go-redis/issues/1343
opt.Username = ""
opt.ClientName = ${ClientName}
opt.DB = ${DB}
opt.PoolSize = ${ConnectionPoolSize}
opt.MinIdleConns = ${ConnectionMinimumIdleSize}

// Set TLS config for redis cloud
if !strings.Contains(${URL}, "localhost") {
    opt.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
    }
}

rdb = redisClient.NewClient(opt)

// Test connection
_, err = rdb.Ping(context.Background()).Result()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Successfully")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Install the **go-redis** package :

```
go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v8
```

#### Import the **go-redis** package :

```
package main
import (
   "context"
   "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"
)
```

#### Create a new Redis client by passing the Redis endpoint and credentials to the `redis.NewClient` function:

```
Client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
   Addr:     "YourRedisEndpoint:YourRedisPort",
   Password: "YourRedisPassword",
   DB:       0, // use default DB
})
```

you have to replace `YourRedisEndpoint`, `YourRedisPort`, and `YourRedisPassword` with the actual values of your **Amazon Elastic Redis cluster**.  Find these values in the **Elasticache console** of your AWS account.

#### Use the Redis client to perform Redis operations. To set a value in Redis, Use the `Set` method:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(time.Second*10))
defer cancel()
err := Client.Set(ctx, "MyKey", "MyValue", 0).Err()
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println("client set error : ",err)
}
```

This will set the value of the `MyKey` key to `MyValue` in Redis.

You can now use the **go-redis** package to connect to your **Amazon Elastic Redis cluster** and perform Redis operations from your Golang code.